# Controller classes in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm digging into Flask with ASP.NET MVC / PHP MVC frameworks background. I'm not sure what is the prefered way of grouping actions (in the sense "function that process request").

In ASP.NET MVC actions are methods, controllers are classes. Controllers can be grouped into Areas. But flask application can be divided into modules and\or blueprints (looks like ASP.NET MVC Areas to me). Neither way uses classes, why?

**Please check the great answer below, another option is [Flask-Classy](https://github.com/apiguy/flask-classy)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just my opinion.

At first in most cases you do not need classes. I can't found cases where I really need classes to just connecting dispatchers to endpoints (I do not told about complex cases where you will use decorators or [Pluggable Views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/)). Do you have many instances of your controllers in `ASP.MVC` and etc? One? What about inheritance? I hope you understand my logic. You also can find interesting topics with `stop writing classes` keywords.

At second in python `module` with `functions` really very similar to `class` (singleton) and `methods`.

At third it just less nested.

For grouping actions I try split controllers (views with flask notation, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20999302/880326) by logic, but you can have more important criterias for this. Easy example:

```
views/
    __init__.py
    about.py
    home.py
    products.py
    user/
        __init__.py
        dashboard.py
        product_1.py
        product_2.py
        product_3.py
        settings.py
```

Comment: I understand your point about classes and yes, my question more about "what structure I should use in Flask to organize my code".

Comment: You can found several interesting projects with `flask skeleton` or `flask examples` keywords and get some information in official documentation (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/ and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/becomingbig/). But however `Flask` give you match flexibility and you can use different patterns for you application. If you need more standard implementation look to popular skeletons and examples.